# Why is related create() checking for id using Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm getting this error:

```
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

when I run:

```
from records.models import Profile

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        p = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
```

I trying to create a profile for each of the existing users.

Profile looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    auto_complete_look_up_field = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_column='AutoCompleteLookUpField', blank=True, null=True)
```

What's happening here? I *would* expect that user_id to exist; that is the user I want to assign to Profile. Why is this even an error?

Comment: It's telling you that a `Profile` already exists for that user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `Profile` already exists for the user you will get this error. You can get around this by using [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) which will only create the new `Profile` if one doesn't already exist

```
profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```